# Overlaying an animation on top of UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

What is the best way to overlay an animated gif on top of a UIView? I have an animation of snowfall that I would like to lay on top of a view, yet still retain interaction with the view below.

Can this be accomplished with UIView animation, or would CoreAnimation be better (for compositing the layers).

Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

One of probably many options would be to set the `UIView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`, then place animation objects behind the view, or use a `UIButton` with a clear bg, etc.

Comment: I could do that, but then whatever is in the main view would sit in front of the animation, I need that animation over top.
Thanks for the thought though!